# How to fix a gap between the x and y axes in core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using `[_graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[_graph allPlots]];`

and if where none of the plots has a y value of 0, there is a gap between the bottom of the Y axis and the X axis.

I've tried using `_graph.axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);`
as well as a calculated yMin instead of 0.0.

Yet, I still get this:
[image]

I've also tried to rescale the plot space, thus:

`[_graph.defaultPlotSpace setPlotRange:r forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateY];`

but couldn't figure out how to set a new minLimit for r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axisConstraints` to position the x-axis at the lower edge of the plot area:

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Comment: Thanks - I discovered this in another post about 10 minutes ago :-)